# What is the difference between property and state?

Tags: android

From [A beginners guide to implement Android Animations](https://medium.com/@shubham.bestfriendforu/a-beginners-guide-to-implement-android-animations-part-1-2-part-series-b5fce1fc85)

> View Animations — They are used to do simple animations like changing
>   size, position, rotation, control transparency. They are easy to build
>   and are very fast but have their own constraints. For eg — Their state
>   changes but their property does not change. View animations will be
>   covered in part 2.

From what I understand, there are properties and states for Views. What is the difference?

Comment: Its a subjective term. Why do you worry about an article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your continue reading that same page:

> The problem with View Animations is that, though the View state changes, its property still remains at the original position. That means, if a ImageButton is moved from 0 to 100 pixels to the right, though it will animate to right, the touch(property) of image button will still be at 0th position.

In other words, property animation changes a property of a view. This can be `translationX` or `translationY` or `alpha`. The `ValueAnimator` gives you a new value for that property each frame, and you are setting that property to that value. When you translate the view, the view is *actually* moving.

View animations are different. They only changes the apparent appearance of the view. Say for example you did a `ScaleAnimation`, you wouldn't see a change in the view's top and left properties. You'll only see that the view enlarges or shrinks. Its frame, as far as the `View` object is concerned is not changed.

I don't remember "state" and "property" as official android terms. It might just be terminology that only that article uses.